# Change first char to uppercase

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

In this task I need to change first char to uppercase. Problem is i'm sending pointer array and I cant change it.

Main:

```
  char *mat1[10], *mat2[10];
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    mat1[i]=(char*)malloc(10);

        scanf("%s", mat1[i]);
    }


function( mat1,mat2, n, &j);//here I strcpy from mat1 to mat2 some words

    change(mat2);
```

Function:

```
void change(char **mat2)
{
    char *p=strdup(*mat2);
    int n=strlen(p);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            p[i]=toupper(p[i]);

        }
        printf("%c ", p[i]);
    }
}
```

Problem is to access letters of a array. E.G.: today is a good day, i need Today is a good day with . at the end. It works only in function (uppercase).

Comment: Why do you have arrays of pointers (for `mat1` and `mat2` anyway)? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (where you actually initialize the arrays, and don't show the arrays you don't use).

Comment: And to change the first character of a string to upper-case all you need is `string[0] = toupper(string[0])`

Comment: I needed to store strings from mat1 to mat2 only if it's every second word in mat1

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it only works in function i need get it back to mat2 in main

Comment: "_it only works in function_ is ambiguous - you don't provide this "working" code, so it is not useful information

Comment: Your code looks ill advised at best.  You might post a question asking how to do this without such complexity.  For starters, `mat1` is only ever 10x10 - dynamic memory allocation is unnecessary.  Also in `change()` assign `p[0]=toupper(p[0]);` _before_ the loop. Testing `i == 0` on every iteration when `i` is deterministic is pointless, and suggests a lack of thought in this.

Comment: Looks like "cargo cult" code to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to change only the first character of a string, "permanently", you could have a function like

```
char *capitalize(char *string)
{
    string[0] = toupper(string[0]);
    return string;
}
```

It could be used like

```
mat2[0] = strdup("today is a good day");
captialize(mat2[0]);
printf("%s\n", mat2[0]);
free(mat2[0]);
```

Should print

```
Today is a good day
```

---

If you want to capitalize all strings in e.g. `mat2` then call this in a loop:

```
void capitalize_all(char **string_array, size_t count)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        capitalize(string_array[i]);
    }
}
```

Call as

```
capitialize_all(mat2, 10);
```

Comment: It doesnt work since i send recieve mat2 as **mat2 and strdup doesnt work

Comment: @Momo Are you trying to captialize *all* strings in `mat2`, or only one?

Comment: Only one but I dont know words. This "today is a good day" was example I cant mat2[0]=strdup(mat2);

 because I have a pointer on mat2

Comment: Only first char I want capitalise !!! I know how to capitalise whole words, but here is a pointer. So i need only first char

Comment: But it doesnt return anything, problem is with mat2[0]=strdup(mat2[0]);

Comment: @Momo My function does, both directly and *indirectly*. See [for example here](https://godbolt.org/z/-i_D-v) for a working example of it being used.

Comment: But i dont mat2[0] = strdup("today is a good day");
I need mat2[0] = strdup(mat2);
I dont know the input

Answer (score 0):

```
string.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + string.substring(1, string.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `change()` you are modifying the duplicate, then discarding the reference to it, producing both a memory leak *and* not modifying the target string.

You have considerably overcomplicated the problem.

Consider:

```
void change(char** p)
{
    *p[0] = toupper( *p[0] ) ;
    printf("%s ", *p ) ;
}
```

The double indirection here is in fact unnecessary, since you only access the `mat2[0]` from the caller. In that case:

```
void change(char** p)
{
    p[0] = toupper( p[0] ) ;
    printf("%s ", p ) ;
}
```

In this case, it would be good practice also to return the string:

```
char* change(char *p)
{
    p[0] = toupper( p[0] ) ;
    printf("%s ", p ) ;

    return p ;
}
```